# Using django models inside celery tasks

Tags: python, django-celery

I have a use case, where I need to import some of my `django` models inside the `celery.py` file in a `django-celery` standard project.

My project looks like follows:

```
|-- backend
|   |-- backend
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- celery.py
|   |   |-- settings.py
|   |   |-- urls.py
|   |   `-- wsgi.py
|   |-- bobbers
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- admin.py
|   |   |-- apps.py
|   |   |-- models.py
|   |   |-- serializers.py
|   |   |-- tests.py
|   |   |-- urls.py
|   |   `-- views.py
|   |-- manage.py
|   |-- requirements.txt
```

All the contents of the celery related files (`backend/backend/__init__.py`, and `backend/backend/celery.py`) are exactly as indicated in the [official docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

But once I add the line `import bobbers.models as bobber_models` to my `celery.py` file, I get the infamous `AppRegistryNotReady` error with the following stacktrace:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 87, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 249, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 132, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Needless to say, if I remove the import, all goes well.

So how can I safely import `django` models in the same file where I write my `celery` tasks?

Comment: The question is why do you need to do this?

Comment: Because my tasks do some heavy calculation and update parameters in the models. They also need model's attributes for the calculations

Comment: Can you provide some high-level example? i mean, without code.

Comment: I have a one to many relationship between two models, A and B. B has a numeric value. A has millions of B. I want to asynchronically update some parameter X of A that depends on the numeric values of B and the updating is a complex operation

Comment: why don't you define a tasks.py  as suggested in here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application

Comment: because i'm in a django-celery setup, I believe what I am asking is pretty standard

Comment: I think you need to move backend into bobbers.

Comment: it is not neccesary to use django-celery any more: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html, please consider to upgrade your project.

Comment: @BjoernStiel backend is the project, bobbers is an app, I'm not sure moving it there is the right way to go